# IllegalArgumentException: expected primitive class, but got UnsignedLong

Tags: google-bigquery

Here's the snippet

`        GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential();
         credential.setAccessToken(tv.trim());
          GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
                    TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, CLIENT_ID,CLIENT_SECRET,Arrays.asList(BigqueryScopes.BIGQUERY))
                    .build();

```
    Credential c =  flow.createAndStoreCredential(oauth2callback.tokens, null);

    bigquery = new Bigquery(TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, c);



     Datasets.List datasetRequest = bigquery.datasets().list("real-time-insight");
        DatasetList datasetList = datasetRequest.execute();
        if (datasetList.getDatasets() != null) {
          List<DatasetList.Datasets> datasets = datasetList.getDatasets();
          System.out.println(" ");
          System.out.println("Available datasets\n----------------");
          System.out.println("    "+datasets.toString()+"  ");
          System.out.println(" ");
          for (DatasetList.Datasets dataset : datasets) {
            System.out.format("%s\n", dataset.getDatasetReference().getDatasetId());
            System.out.println(" ");
          }
        }

    /* DatasetList list = bigquery.datasets().list("real-time-insight").execute();
        out.println(list);
        System.out.println("lists are ::  "+list);*/
        String query = "select * from [ajay.export] where From_State like '%Alabama%' LIMIT 1";
      // QueryResponse response=null;



        Job job = new Job();
        JobConfiguration config = new JobConfiguration();
        JobConfigurationQuery queryConfig = new JobConfigurationQuery();
        config.setQuery(queryConfig);

        job.setConfiguration(config);
        queryConfig.setQuery(query);

        Insert insert = bigquery.jobs().insert("real-time-insight", job);

        insert.setProjectId("real-time-insight");
        JobReference jobId = insert.execute().getJobReference();
        System.out.println(" ");

        System.out.println("job id : " +jobId);
        System.out.println(" ");
        Job pollJob = bigquery.jobs().get("real-time-insight", jobId.getJobId()).execute();
        if (pollJob.getStatus().getState().equals("DONE")) 
        {
            System.out.println(" ");
             System.out.format("Job status %s: %s\n", 
               jobId.getJobId(), pollJob.getStatus().getState());
             System.out.println(" ");
        }
        else
        {
             try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        System.out.println("1. here");
        System.out.println(" ");
        System.out.println("poll job id is :: "+pollJob.getJobReference().getJobId());


       String pageToken=null; 
        System.out.println(" ");
        System.out.println("1. here  " );
        System.out.println(" ");

        GetQueryResultsResponse queryResult = bigquery.jobs()
                .getQueryResults(
                    "real-time-insight",  pollJob.getJobReference().getJobId())
                      .setPageToken(pageToken).execute();


        if (queryResult.getJobComplete()) {
              List<TableRow> rows = queryResult.getRows();

                System.out.print("\nQuery Results:\n------------\n");

                for (TableRow row : rows) {
                  for (TableCell field : row.getF()) {
                  System.out.printf("%-50s", field.getV());
                   }
                  System.out.println();
                }

            pageToken = queryResult.getPageToken();
            if (null == pageToken) {
              return;
            }
          }

        System.out.println("12345. here");



       /* List<TableRow> rows = queryResult.getRows();

        System.out.print("\nQuery Results:\n------------\n");

        for (TableRow row : rows) {
          for (TableCell field : row.getF()) {
          System.out.printf("%-50s", field.getV());
           }
          System.out.println();
        }`
```

The stack trace is

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:  [key totalRows, field private com.google.common.primitives.UnsignedLong com.google.api.services.bigquery.model.QueryResponse.totalRows]
    at com.google.api.client.json.JsonParser.parseValue(JsonParser.java:630)
    at com.google.api.client.json.JsonParser.parse(JsonParser.java:342)
    at com.google.api.client.json.JsonParser.parseValue(JsonParser.java:578)
    at com.google.api.client.json.JsonParser.parse(JsonParser.java:281)
    at com.google.api.client.json.JsonObjectParser.parseAndClose(JsonObjectParser.java:87)
    at com.google.api.client.json.JsonObjectParser.parseAndClose(JsonObjectParser.java:81)
    at com.google.api.client.http.HttpResponse.parseAs(HttpResponse.java:459)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:470)
    at com.ajay.oauth.BigQueryHandler1.doGet(BigQueryHandler1.java:61)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
    at com.google.appengine.api.socket.dev.DevSocketFilter.doFilter(DevSocketFilter.java:74)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ResponseRewriterFilter.doFilter(ResponseRewriterFilter.java:127)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.HeaderVerificationFilter.doFilter(HeaderVerificationFilter.java:34)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:63)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:125)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:366)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectModuleRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:349)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doFilter(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:116)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:98)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:490)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:547)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:212)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: expected primitive class, but got: class com.google.common.primitives.UnsignedLong
    at com.google.api.client.util.Data.parsePrimitiveValue(Data.java:453)
    at com.google.api.client.json.JsonParser.parseValue(JsonParser.java:628)

Answer (score 0):

*Disclaimer: I don't have first-hand experience with `BigQuery`, the following is general programming reasoning*:

According to the [Guava docs](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/primitives/UnsignedLong.html), `UnsignedLong` is a wrapper class for unsigned long values. Also according to the docs, it has a `longValue()` method that, as you might expect, returns the value in `long` form.

Somewhere (exactly where isn't immediately apparent in the code you've posted), you have a method that is (probably indirectly) calling `com.google.api.client.util.Data.parsePrimitiveValue(Data.java:453)`, which looks like this ([source](https://code.google.com/p/google-http-java-client/source/browse/google-http-client/src/main/java/com/google/api/client/util/Data.java?r=ab56578406438ebe575ebdbb8bb44725c72d6a6c)):

```
public static Object parsePrimitiveValue(Type type, String stringValue) {
    Class<?> primitiveClass = type instanceof Class<?> ? (Class<?>) type : null;
    ...
    if (primitiveClass == Character.class || primitiveClass == char.class) {....}
    if (primitiveClass == Boolean.class || primitiveClass == boolean.class) {... }

    //checks for each primitive class to see if it matches the type passed in
    //if no primitive type is matched:
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("expected primitive class, but got: " + type);
}
```

Obviously, this method is getting called with a type parameter of `UnsignedLong`. You need to figure out where that's happening (hint: follow the stack trace), then figure out where the parameters passed to it are originating (hint: follow the stack trace further). I bet you'll find a method that does something to the effect of this:

```
someMethod(){
 UnsignedLong val;
 ...
 parsePrimitiveValue(val.getClass().getName(), val.toString());
 ...
}
```

So, figure out how change the call to something to the effect of

```
parsePrimitiveValue(Long.class.getName(),  val.longValue().toString())
```

Comment: thnks for ur help but i am not using any unsigned value it gives me exception as soon as the execute method executed

Comment: @Ajay post your entire stack trace

Comment: @Ajay the *stack trace* - not your code, post everything that gets printed in the console with the exception